# Ruby 1.9.3 compatible memory profiling tools with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling

I'm looking for some tools that are 1.9.3 compatible that can give me some real world usage numbers on the memory a rails program is taking while being used in development. In a perfect world it would be able to break out that memory usage by class, or some way to tell us what can be tweaked. Please only recommend a tool if you've used it and you endorse it.

Answer (score 4):

I've had success with [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof).

It has various ways of obtaining the profile data and presents a lot of information, which can be a bit overwhelming initially. It really solved a problem for me and helped me remove a major bottleneck from something I was working on (I was calling `require` from inside a method, which was being called inside a tight loop... crunch!).

Comment: Were you using ruby-prof for memory profiling, which is what was asked about in this question? The README mentions memory profiling, but it requires a patch, and I suspect the patch is a bit old.

Comment: The patch mentioned that I've found is for 125. I was able to apply it to the gc.c of a 1.9.3-p392 ruby, BUT ruby-prof doesn't appear to see it. Everything runs under the patched ruby, but I get no Memory numbers. I DO get timing numbers if I use that mode, however.